# Sharing an image link at the time of upload to facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, passport.js

For a variety of reasons I won't go into, I am unable to upload photos to a user's FB account from a standalone kiosk application.

As an alternative what I would like to try is

1- the user logs in to their FB account with name & password 
2- the photo gets uploaded to one common admin account, 
3- just the link to this uploaded photo gets posted to the user's feed.

So in essence there would be 2 login + uploads.
The first would be hidden from the user and have the hardcoded email+pw for the common admin account. The photo would be uploaded here.
The 2nd would be the one the user sees and would control just the posting of the link to the previously uploaded photo.
Can any facebook experts chime in and suggest whether this is possible?

I am using a local node.js,passport, express server to handle login and authentication.

Comment: You would not store the login credentials of the admin (because you can’t effectively do anything with them anyway, there is no API to perform login with credentials), but only their access token.

Comment: But kiosk applications with user login are a bad idea anyway, they can easily lead to problems, because Facebook’s security systems will consider a lot of different logins from a single device over a short period of time as suspicious. The mildest possible consequence is that users might have to perform additional verification upon login, but it can go up to users getting their accounts blocked based on suspicion they might have been hacked, and your app getting blocked as well. If at all possible, rather use Device Login for this.

Comment: Thanks. In the past have used user login with kiosks without issue. At most there is roughly a dozen or so uploads per day. Using device login complicates the user login experience further by adding yet another dialog in the user flow. There are already 2 extended permission dialogs a user has to click thru AFTER logging in to simply upload a photo to their fb account. I am trying to streamline the user experience.